# How to re-activate Lazyload when navigating between tabs?

Tags: tabs, jquery-lazyload

I used zurb's foundation for a website which had lots of images distributed over some tabs.
It was very heavy to load so I used jQuery Lazyload to solve the problem. It worked beautifully except for the fact that it only loads the images on the 1st tab, which is the one active by default. The images in other tabs only loaded upon scrolling. Even if you do it by just a tiny bit.

So how do I re-activate Lazyload when navigating between tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried many fixes, including the ones in Lazyload's on website. None of them worked when the content is inside tabs. 
But as *Lazyload is triggered by scrolling* I've managed to activate it by moving the page only 1px. Which is practically unnoticeable.

Here's how to do it in two simple steps...

add this javascript to the bottom of the **body** tag inside your **html** file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      // FUNCTION TO SCROLL 1PX AND TRIGGER THE LAZY LOAD
      function tinyScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0, 1);
      }
</script>
```

and add **onclick="tinyscroll()"** to your *tabs*. Like this example

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="tinyScroll()" class="tab"><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li onclick="tinyScroll()" class="tab"><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li onclick="tinyScroll()" class="tab"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: cool trick! especially when you are dealing with files vendor keeps updating and you cant modify them to risk replacement during updates

Answer (score 0):

Your own answer is clearly a bad hack. In general I would recommend to use [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes). Among other improvements, it detects any image visibility changes automatically. So you don't have to bother to trigger anything.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. This was supposed to inform others of a simple hack. I know it's a bad one but it solves the problem. I did not take the time to try your plugin _lazySizes_ but I will next time I need lazy loading. Thanks for the reply and for making your plugin available to everyone. [Thank you, but I prefer it my way](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/de/de657619fcf82dfd869a370f3337ff704f1a82fb3ba4aeddb6022dbb50d10ec9.jpg) - Lol.

Comment: if you are dealing with something like WordPress plugin and you cant ask them to use LazySizes then Bruce Santos hack can help..